# Windows 10 UWP App: GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker; Failed to launch browser exception

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client, google-api-webmasters

Hoping someone has come across this issue before;

I am building a Universal Windows Platform (UWP) App on Windows 10 that consumes data from the Google Web Master Tools API and when I try to authorise using the Google Web Authorization Broker I run into the following exception:

> InnerException = {System.NotSupportedException: Failed to launch browser with "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?access_type=offline&response_type=code&client_id=437110116900-jfsnbikhkj8l4aetubtkn52ggki45nm0.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http:%2F%2F127....

Code snippet:

```
string[] scopes = new string[] {
                WebmastersService.Scope.Webmasters
            };

using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secret.json",
                                   FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                {
                    UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    scopes,
                    userName,
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(".", true)).Result;
                }
```

Thanks in advance :)

Cheers,
Paul

Comment: I found this little gem in the release notes for the control:

- UWP (will build, but is known not to work at runtime)

Seems I'm wasting my time with this method.

Answer (score 0):

The [Google APIs .net client library](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client) does not support UWP at this time.  see [Investigate UWP support #983](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/983)

The problem is launching the browser to authenticate the library doesn't have the ability to do so on a UWP app.

Comment: is it still the case today?

Comment: there is no change it's still not supported

Comment: I am using xamarin forms with .net standard 2.0, do you know if it is possible to get that working in .net standard 2.0 project without going into UWP level?

Comment: xamarin isn't supposed and to my knowledge we have no plans for support in the near future.    UWP support is planned but no idea when